# Trying to link Static j.s file with my html file in Django....but facing some issues

Tags: javascript, html

**Error:**

> TemplateSyntaxError at /studentUpdate/Invalid block tag on line 67: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

**Here is my Html file:-**

```
    {% extends 'app.html' %}

    {% block body %}
        <div>


            <div class="alert alert-info">All Students</div>





            <button id="show_book" type="button"  class="btn btn-success"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left">
            </span> Back
            </button>


       <div id="edit_form"></div>

            <div id="book_form" > 
                <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">

               <!-- <form id="form" > -->

                        {% csrf_token %}

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Student ID:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="sid" required="required" class="form-control"/> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>First name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Last name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Department:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="department" class="form-control" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Section:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="section" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Year:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="year" class="form-control"/>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button id="edit_book" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
                                Update

                            </button>
                        </div>
                <!--    </form>  -->
                </div> 
                </div>

                </div>

            <% load staticfiles %>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'indexx.js' %}">       </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

**Here is my indexx.js file is stored:-**
C:\Users\abhishek\OneDrive\Desktop\T.A Library MNGNT SYS\django-library-management-system-master\library\static\indexx.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html file add :

`{% load static %}`

just after the line :

```
 {% extends 'app.html' %}
```

and remove

```
<% load staticfiles %>
```

And make sure that your js file is stored in the static folder only.

that's all you have to do.

I hope it will help you!!